# I need to connect a Windows 7 computer to a workgroup

Tags: windows-7, networking, passwords, user-accounts

The computer in question, the account doesn't have a password to connect, but apparently to connect to other computers (for file sharing), it needs to log into an account that has a password.  In doing this, Windows 7 prompts for a login.  The default is MYCOMPUTER\username, or if I type a different account, I fail to login, and proposes MYCOMPUTER\differentaccount as the login.

Likewise if I specify server\username as the account, and type the password (If I go to the Win7 computer acting as a server, I can login fine using these credentials), I get "The specified network password is incorrect."

Finally, I have a third computer on the network which has an account with a password and the server has an account with matching name and password, and this works automatically.

Is there a solution other than applying a password to the client computer account and using a matching account on the server?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  Are you trying to access resources on other computers in the network, or log in to them all using the same account?

Comment: Access resources on the network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the reasons for using [Active Directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Directory) instead of workgroups. If you are not going to use a Active Directory domain your only other option is to do the matching passwords or just live with the prompts showing up.

Comment: I remember a long time ago Active Directory and domains were only available with Windows Server OS's.  Is that still so, or is this changed in Windows 7?

Comment: Windows 7 requires [either versions "Professional", "Ultimate", or "Enterprise"](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/connect-your-computer-to-a-domain) to join a domain. However, you will need at least one computer somewhere on your network running a server version of the OS to act as the [domain controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_controller).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  So because I don't have a server OS handy and don't want to get one, I must go the "same account name, same password" route.  Right?

Comment: Yes, I believe so, but there may be other option I can't think of.

Comment: It appears I accidentally discovered that by setting a password on the user's local account, it enables access to other accounts on the network.  As long as the local account has no password, it appears no amount of finagling will gain access to another computer.  Thanks for your effort Scott.